# Pycharm won't import Conda module

Tags: python, pycharm, python-imaging-library, conda

I'm using Python 3.5 and I was trying to download and use Pillow 4.0.0. I got it through Conda, and it shows in its package menu, as well as the module list in Pycharm. However, even when I have the project interpreter set to anaconda, it will not recognize Pillow at all. I've also given it some time to scan through everything, to see if that would work.

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate pycharm's cache and restart?

Comment: I have restarted it, but how would I invalidate the cache? Edit: Doing it now, fingers crossed

Comment: @adgon92 it did not work :/

Answer (score 1):

Invalidating the caches and restarting would work. If you want to refresh the Pycharm cache, try going to the far left of PyCharm, and choose [File|Invalidate Caches/Restart...]